# Protractor-net and Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, protractor-net

I'm new to Protractor and am wanting to write C# tests that run against an Angular 8 application.  The problem is, the application uses Azure AD for authentication and I don't know the correct approach to authenticate automatically when running the test.  If I navigate to the application URL it redirects to the Microsoft login page for authentication but I can't seem to access this.

Comment: One approach that I've seen that has worked is to acquire tokens using the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow for a test user, injecting them to local/session storage, and then running the tests. I would recommend you don't attempt to automate the login page, as there are automated checks performed on logins there that might block you. Sadly I don't have a code sample for this :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libraries given by Microsoft to implement applications for authenticating to Azure.MSAL is one of the libreary whiich is best to use. If you want to use MSAL to acquire a token, you need to:

1. Register an application in Azure AD.
2. Add target API, and grant consent to select permissions.
3. Generate a secret key.

Then you can get a token as [Acquire a token and call Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop).

However, I think what you really want is to integrate AAD. You can easily [enable AAD authentication for your .NET web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp).  It uses `OWIN` middleware.